# Does Hadoop Streaming's performance decrease if I use -mapper cat rather than -mapper org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, elastic-map-reduce

I have had problems trying to use org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper as the argument of -mapper in Hadoop Streaming 1.0.3. "cat" works though; does using cat affect performance -- especially on Elastic MapReduce?

Comment: I think there's no huge difference in performance, except `cat` commands relies on cluster of *nix slaves when java realization is common.

Comment: Any task (map, reduce) is executing on tasktrackers (or container in yarn). I've meant that you could use cat command only on *nix servers. Please, post your code for clarifying question, how you run you Job?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, where identity mapper didn't work and I'd have to use `Cat`.

We did not see a huge change in performance and as I know *identity mapper* is a jar vs *cat* is unix command.